# How to update files between 2 container with shared volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, continuous-delivery

## Situation

Let's say, we have two containers, A and B.

A and B have shared name volume as: `shared-volume`.
`A container` have `shared-volume` mount to `/root/shareA`.
`B container` have `shared-volume` mount to `/root/shareB`.

This mean, when we go to `B container` and create file `"example.txt"` in `/root/shareB`. At `A container`, we can have access to `"example.txt"`, making `A container` and `B container` have a shared volume thourgh `shared-volume`.

I am using docker-compose for this:

```
version: '2.1'

volumes:
    shared-volume:

services:
  A:
    image: imageA
    volumes:
        - shared-volume:/root/sharedA

  B:
    image: imageB
    volumes:
        - shared-volume:/root/sharedB
```

## The Problem

I am using `imageB` as container for storing code & resources, `imageA` would be some thing like consumer, web server, which will use files in `imageB`. `imageA` and `imageB` share file via named volume (which was shown as above).

As what I have tested, `imageB` share file successfully with `imageA`.

Problem is, when I update `imageB` with newer files, shared volumne's file still stay the same. I have to remove all containers and volumes, start it again, then newer files was applied.
Which mean I have to run `docker-compose down -v` then `docker-compose up -d`.

`imageA` was some thing like web server, which should never be downed for any reason.

I wonder if I have mistakes some where or missing somethings to make `imageA` can get newer code from `imageB` without shutdown `imageA` and it's volume?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker believes that volumes are there to contain critical user data, and it doesn't know anything about their contents.  If you're relying on Docker's behavior where it will populate a named volume on first use from an image, if you change the underlying container, it won't update the volume, since it might be corrupting user data.

That is, in your situation:

1. Docker Compose creates the `shared-volume`.
2. Docker launches `B` attaching `shared-volume` to it.  Since `shared-volume` is empty, it is populated from `imageB`.
3. You rebuild `imageB` and re-run `docker-compose up`.
4. Docker launches `B` attaching `shared-volume` to it.  Since `shared-volume` is not empty, it keeps the content it had from the previous run.

Volumes are not an appropriate place to store code or libraries.  In the completely abstract case as you've described it, your code should be built into `imageA` (which is running it), and when you change it, you should rebuild both images.  `docker-compose up --build` can do this for you.

Your question hints at a layout where the `A` container is something like an Nginx or Apache Web server, and from its point of view the "code and images" are just static JavaScript and PNG files that it's serving; they are "data".  In that setup it would be appropriate to mount a data volume on to `/var/www`, but whatever build tool produces the output needs to explicitly copy it into the volume.  One easy solution (assuming a JavaScript/Webpack project) is to bind-mount your project's `dist` directory and `npm run build` on the host, instead of using a container for it.

Since the automatic Docker data copy only happens the very first time the container is run, you might need to manually copy data at startup time if it's important to have it in a volume.  You can do this with an entrypoint script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Copy application assets to the shared directory
cp -a ./assets /root/shared

# Run the CMD as the main container process
exec "$@"
```

```sh
# At the end of your Dockerfile
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD as before
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it was the only solution for me right now. I wonder if there are any other best practices for CD resources without affect running applications?

Comment: I've searched the whole internet in the hope there is a simple solution to that simple problem. Unfortunately, docker is as quirky as PHP. Docker progressed a bit since 2014(first time I used docker) but it's still focused on "simplicity" sometimes turning simple problems into complex nightmare.

I'd consider following solutions as simple, but docker doesn't provide this functionality:
1. a security switch to turn on overwriting existing volume data.
2. temporary volumes, eg. shareable tmpfs or automatically removable volumes.
3. docker compose cp directive for a service.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, if there were some sort of flexibility like @DieterPisarewski said, e.g temporary volumes or some config for a volume, it would have been great.